# Authentication for my API on separate domain

Tags: api, authentication, heroku

I am trying to create an API that I can leverage for multiple client applications (web, mobile, etc..) I am hosting the API on Heroku, so the API address will be something like foo.herokuapp.com.

I want to serve all requests through this, but I also want to have a separate web client to interact with it, say, bar.herokuapp.com

Right now, I have authentication over HTTPS using cookies working well on the API's domain, but how do I authenticate requests from the web client (bar.herokuapp.com) to the API (foo.herokuapp.com) since it is on a separate domain?

Comment: What type of authentication do you use in foo.herokuapp.com? Is the webapp something like an SPA ?

Comment: Yes, bar.herokuapp.com will be something like a SPA. I am using Passport, a Node.js module for auth on the API (foo.herokuapp.com), and it is sending a cookie back in order to authenticate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use cookie based authentication in foo.herokuapp.com you can change the scope of the cookie to be `.herokuapp.com` this way CORS requests with `withCredentials` from `bar.herokuapp.com` will send the cookie.

**One problem I see though, is that herokuapp.com is not YOURS.** Someone else could create an application in heroku, redirect your users there and stole the cookie. Then they will be able to call your api with the stolen cookie. So, I will strongly recommend you to buy a domain, otherwise do not use this approach.

Another approach that works very well for this case is to use JSON Web Tokens check [Cookies vs Tokens](http://blog.auth0.com/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/).